Squareup appointment iframe embed
Does anyone know how to embed a booking flow from square on a custom website? Using Angular to add an iframe that pops up when clicking a button that will take you to the appointment booking section.
Here's how I'm currently doing it:
.html
<iframe
  [src]="getSanitizedURL()"
  allow="payment https://squareup.com"
  frameborder="0"
  sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts"></iframe>


.ts
import {
  AfterViewInit,
  ChangeDetectorRef,
  Component,
  Inject
} from '@angular/core';
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

interface DialogData {
  dialogURL: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-third-party-dialog',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './third-party-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrl: './third-party-dialog.component.scss'
})
export class ThirdPartyDialogComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData,
    private readonly domSanitizer: DomSanitizer,
    private ref: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {}

  /*
    Prevent iframe from reloading on mobile.
    Whenever there was a scroll while iframe is open,
    it caused a reload. To fix, we call detach() :)
    Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54204166/4036593
  */
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.ref.detach();
  }

  getSanitizedURL(): SafeResourceUrl {
    return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(
      this.data.dialogURL
    );
  }
}


But I get these errors:
Content-Security-Policy: The page’s settings blocked an event handler (script-src-attr) from being executed because it violates the following directive: “script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://www.googletagmanager.com https://*.doubleclick.net https://www.googleadservices.com https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js https://www.gstatic.com https://*.contentsquare.com https://*.contentsquare.net https://connect.facebook.net https://cdn.sprig.com https://*.squarecdn.com https://js.squareup.com https://cdn.cookielaw.org”

and clicking any services I get:
Uncaught DOMException: A parameter or an operation is not supported by the underlying object
    h https://booking-flow-production-c.squarecdn.com/assets/index-VBxawTeB.js:139
    onClick https://booking-flow-production-c.squarecdn.com/assets/index-VBxawTeB.js:139
    yQ https://booking-flow-production-c.squarecdn.com/assets/index-VBxawTeB.js:35
    SQ https://booking-flow-production-c.squarecdn.com/assets/index-VBxawTeB.js:35
    _Q https://booking-flow-production-c.squarecdn.com/assets/index-VBxawTeB.js:35
    B$ https://booking-flow-production-c.squarecdn.com/assets/index-VBxawTeB.js:35
    yD https://booking-flow-production-c.squarecdn.com/assets/index-VBxawTeB.js:35
    OS https://booking-flow-production-c.squarecdn.com/assets/index-VBxawTeB.js:35
    X6 https://booking-flow-production-c.squarecdn.com/assets/index-VBxawTeB.js:38
    HL https://booking-flow-production-c.squarecdn.com/assets/index-VBxawTeB.js:35
    OS https://booking-flow-production-c.squarecdn.com/assets/index-VBxawTeB.js:35
    C6 https://booking-flow-production-c.squarecdn.com/assets/index-VBxawTeB.js:35
    MQ https://booking-flow-production-c.squarecdn.com/assets/index-VBxawTeB.js:35
    bD https://booking-flow-production-c.squarecdn.com/assets/index-VBxawTeB.js:35
    kS https://booking-flow-production-c.squarecdn.com/assets/index-VBxawTeB.js:35
    Hm https://booking-flow-production-c.squarecdn.com/assets/index-VBxawTeB.js:35
    Hm https://booking-flow-production-c.squarecdn.com/assets/index-VBxawTeB.js:35
    createRoot https://booking-flow-production-c.squarecdn.com/assets/index-VBxawTeB.js:38
    FQe https://booking-flow-production-c.squarecdn.com/assets/index-VBxawTeB.js:281
    async* https://booking-flow-production-c.squarecdn.com/assets/index-VBxawTeB.js:281
    <anonymous> https://booking-flow-production-c.squarecdn.com/assets/index-VBxawTeB.js:281
index-VBxawTeB.js:139


2 weeks ago this was working fine, and then suddenly stop working.
tried calling square support, changing ways to embed it, using the script file.

i have a bit of a unrelated question when the iframe loads does it redirect you when you clikc on a service ?

Yes! that is exactly what is now happening, and I'm questioning whether it is something that Square intentionally did.

I've checked that line of the file and seems there are references to some origins that aren't listed in your Content Security Policy. Specifically 'https://api.squareup.com' and 'https://app.squareup.com'. Though maybe just allowing the former would be enough to solve the CSP issue and maybe then that error would disappear.

After trying for a while, I still haven’t been able to fix the issue. Anyone know how to correctly add those to the CSP in angular?
